# Radio box enabling input fields with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

I'm trying to enable a textfield based on which option is chosen in a radio button. I'm just really new to any javascript or jquery, so I really need some help.

This is the TR from a table where the radio buttons and input fields are placed

```
<tr>
    <td><b>Yes or no?</b></td>
    <td><input id="yes" type="radio" name="choose" value="yes"> Yes</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><input id="no" type="radio" name="choose" value="no" checked> No</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="disabledtextfield" id="test" disabled />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('#no').click(function () {
                $('#test').removeAttr("disabled");
            });

            $('#yes').click(function () {
                $('#test').attr("disabled", "disabled");
            });
        </script>
    </td>
</tr>
```

The problem is probably really trivial, but again, I haven't worked with this at all. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like like following using `change` event instead of `click`.

```js
$(':radio[name=choose]').change(function () {
    var isChecked = $('#yes').is(':checked');
    $('#test').prop("disabled", !isChecked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><b>Yes or no?</b></td>
        <td><input id="yes" type="radio" name="choose" value="yes"> Yes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input id="no" type="radio" name="choose" value="no" checked> No</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="disabledtextfield" id="test" disabled />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I'm sorry for this stupid question, but where do I paste the javascript code? In the <script> tags?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your code in document ready function

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
                    $('#no').click(function()
                            {
                              $('#test').removeAttr("disabled");
                            });

                    $('#yes').click(function()
                            {
                              $('#test').attr("disabled","disabled");
                            });
        })
                    </script>
```

```js
$('#no').click(function()
                    {
                      $('#test').removeAttr("disabled");
                    });

            $('#yes').click(function()
                    {
                      $('#test').attr("disabled","disabled");
                    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><b>Yes or no?</b></td>
        <td><input id="yes" type="radio" name="choose" value="yes" checked> Yes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input id="no" type="radio" name="choose" value="no" > No</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="disabledtextfield" id="test" disabled />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```